# nginx + OpenSSL Install

Tags: installation, http, openssl, nginx

```
CHANGES
LICENSE
README
conf
contrib
man
openssl-1.0.0d
pcre-8.12
src/
CHANGES.ru
Makefile
auto
configure
html/
objs/
openssl-1.0.0d.tar.gz
pcre-8.12.tar.gz


./configure ./configure --with-pcre=/pcre-8.12 --with-openssl=/openssl-1.0.0d
checking for OpenSSL md5 crypto library ... not found

./configure: error: the HTTP cache module requires md5 functions from OpenSSL library.
```

You can either disable the module by using `--without-http-cache option`, or install the OpenSSL library into the system, or build the OpenSSL library statically from the source with nginx by using `--with-http_ssl_module --with-openssl=<path>` options.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the libssl development headers. This requires the `libssl-dev` package (should be in the repository, or go [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/libssl-dev) for the package file.